# Subset elements in a list based on a logical condition

Tags: list, r, conditional-statements

How can I subset a list based on a condition (TRUE, FALSE) in another list? Please, see my example below:

```
l <- list(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6,5), c=c(3,4,5,6))
l
$a
[1] 1 2 3

$b
[1] 4 5 6 5

$c
[1] 3 4 5 6

cond <- lapply(l, function(x) length(x) > 3)
cond
$a
[1] FALSE

$b
[1] TRUE

$c
[1] TRUE

> l[cond]
```

> Error in l[cond] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`[` is expecting a vector, so use `unlist` on `cond`:

```
l[unlist(cond)]
$b
[1] 4 5 6 5

$c
[1] 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 44):

This is what the `Filter` function was made for:

```
Filter(function(x) length(x) > 3, l)
$b
[1] 4 5 6 5

$c
[1] 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: Simple. Base R. Love it!

Comment: The drawback of Filter is that you can't use for assignments, as opposed to James' and PatrickR's answers.

Answer (score 30):

Another way is to use `sapply` instead of `lapply`.

```
cond <- sapply(l, function(x) length(x) > 3)
l[cond]
```

Comment: This produces just the object cond, the the result of the subset.

Comment: To clarify, l[cond] now produces the subset as sapply returns a vector.  Edited to add this.

Answer (score 5):

```
> l[as.logical(cond)]
$b
[1] 4 5 6 5

$c
[1] 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 4):

I recently learned `lengths()`, which gets the length of each element of a list. This allows us to avoid making another list including logical values as the OP tried.

```
lengths(l)
#a b c 
#3 4 4
```

Using this in a logical condition, we can subset list elements in `l`.

```
l[lengths(l) > 3]

$b
[1] 4 5 6 5

$c
[1] 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Well im am very new to R but as it is a functional language by far the best solution according to the previous answers is something like:

```
filter <- function (inputList, selector) sapply(inputList, function (element) selector(element))
```

Assume you have a complex list like yours:

```
myList <- list(
    a=c(1,2,3), 
    b=c(4,5,6,5), 
    c=c(3,4,5,6))
```

Then you can filter the elements like:

```
selection <- myList[filter(myList, function (element) length(element) > 3]
```

Well of course this also works for list that just contain a value at the first level:

```
anotherList <- list(1, 2, 3, 4)
selection <- myList[filter(anotherList, function (element) element == 2)]
```

Or you can put it all together like:

```
filter <- function (inputList, selector) inputList[sapply(inputList, function (element) selector(element))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cond <- lapply(l, length) > 3
l[cond]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l <- list(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6,5), c=c(3,4,5,6))

l[lengths(l) > 3]

$b
[1] 4 5 6 5

$c
[1] 3 4 5 6
```

If a condition on *value* is needed:

```
cond <- lapply(l, function(i) i > 3)

res <- Map(`[`, l, cond)

res

$a
numeric(0)

$b
[1] 4 5 6 5

$c
[1] 4 5 6
```