# How to remove dataframes where nrow<n from a list of dataframes?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes, ranging in size. I want to drop those with few rows (lets say <3).

This is what I've been working with so far, for what it's worth:

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1 = c(1, 2, 3, 9), y2 = c(4, 5, 6, 7))
d2 <- data.frame(y1 = c(3, 2, 1, 6), y2 = c(6, 5, 4, 4))
d3 <- data.frame(y1 = c(3, 2), y2 = c(6, 5))
d4 <- data.frame(y1 = c(3, 2), y2 = c(6, 5))
listdfs <- list(d1, d2, d3, d4)


listdfs2<-lapply(listdfs,function(x) if(nrow<10<-NULL)))
```

So basically d1 and 2 should be maintained.

Thanks.

Comment: A possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941506/subset-elements-in-a-list-based-on-a-logical-condition/8935399.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
listdfs[lapply(listdfs, nrow) > 3]

[[1]]
  y1 y2
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  6
4  9  7

[[2]]
  y1 y2
1  3  6
2  2  5
3  1  4
4  6  4
```

Comment: `sapply` rather than `lapply`

Comment: what's he advantage in this case?

Comment: You want to supply to `<` a integer vector, not a list of integer scalars.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by `Filter`, i.e.

```
Filter(function(i) nrow(i) > 3, listdfs)

[[1]]
  y1 y2
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  6
4  9  7

[[2]]
  y1 y2
1  3  6
2  2  5
3  1  4
4  6  4
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `discard` from `purrr`

```
purrr::discard(listdfs, ~ nrow(.) < 3)

[[1]]
  y1 y2
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  6
4  9  7

[[2]]
  y1 y2
1  3  6
2  2  5
3  1  4
4  6  4
```